# Problem with removing part of string while using join

Tags: sql, left-join

I'm trying to create a resources report using a select query against mutliple tables.
The report is fine except that i wish to remove part of a string on some values when presented.
Some of our resources names has the domain name included in the name like "myresource1.my.domain.com"
In the result of the query i don't want the domain part of name to be shown.

The table "Resources" has got the column RESOURCENAME which has the string for the resources names.

Example on how the Resources table looks like but it got many more columns than this.

| RESOURCEID | RESOURCENAME |
| --- | --- |
| 18456 | computer1.my.domain.com |
| 26425 | computer2.local |
| 36415 | tablet1 (without domain name but with text inside theese parentheses) |
| 49400 | smartphone1 (IMEI code) |
| 23544 | computer3.my.domain.com |

What i got so far in the query is this but im missing the part where i select the Resources.RESOURCENAME but stripped from the domain part in the string.

```
SELECT
res.RESOURCEID 'Resource ID',
--Here i would like to get res.RESOURCENAME but if the string ends with .my.domain.com or .local i want that domain part of the string removed.
FROM Resources res
--left join 'Here i have a couple of left join that works as expected'
--left join 'Here i have a couple of left join that works as expected'
```

Anyone who can help me here?

Regards
Larsa

Comment: Move the ct conditions from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result. As it now, they make the LEFT JOIN return regular INNER JOIN result.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! And don't forget to specify the expected result. I.e. [mcve].

Comment: @jarlh
I'm sorry for messing it up, I can feel myself that things get messy, guess because i'm from Sweden and having a hard time explaining myself in English :)
Does the edit i've done clear things up?

Comment: Klart bättre nu.

Comment: No one who can give me a hint?